# CSS to force next li below?

Tags: css, list

I have a list set of list items that I use for displaying projects. I was wondering how to make so the next list item appears under each other rather than beside.

[image]

Edit sorry included code.

```
<li class="project-item">
<div class="project-list-wrap">

    <div class="projectpicture" style="background-image: url();"></div>

    <h2 class="project-list-title">
        <a href="">yu mk</a>
    </h2>
    <div class="project-list-info">
        <span>Posted July 20, 2017</span>
        <span>0 Bids</span>
                    <span>$444.00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="project-list-desc">
        <p>asdfsd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project-list-skill"><span class="fre-label"><a href="">Facebook</a></span></div>        <!-- <div class="project-list-bookmark">
        <a class="fre-bookmark" href="">Bookmark</a>
    </div> -->
</div>
```

and the CSS for the photo

```
.projectpicture {

    width: 360px;
    height: 224px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
 }
```

CSS for other

```
.project-list-wrap {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

project-list-title {
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}


.project-list-info {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: If you didn't show your CSS & HTML , how can we help?

Comment: post your code. `li`'s display underneath one another by default.

Comment: we don't need image,send html and css please!

Comment: Wasn't thinking. I've added the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need clear the floats on the list items. So:

```
.project-item { clear: both; }
```